# Не удается загрузить DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

```
Ex: System.DllNotFoundException: Не удается загрузить DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

в System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize()
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework)
   в esr.Models.MailbirdEmailClient.SelectSqlCommand(String sqlCommand)
   в esr.Models.MailbirdEmailClient.GetAccounts()

Comment: Данная ошибка появляется только после сборки проекта в инсталятор. В режиме дебага всё работает нормально

Comment: Вероятно, потому что ты не включил эту библиотеку в сборку? :)

Comment: В сборку включены все те библиотеки которые и в проекте проверил ранее

Comment: @krekerkreker07: А SQLite.Interop.dll среди них есть?

Comment: Установите в подключаемых библиотеках SQLite настройку копирования в выходной каталог. Возможно (скорее всего) в режиме Release они не копируются.